# Raw Sockets on BSD Operating Systems

Tags: c, sockets, bsd

I've been writing some sockets code in C. I need modify packet headers and control how they're sent out, so I took the raw sockets approach. However, the code I wrote will not compile on BSD systems (Mac OS X/Darwin, FreeBSD, etc.)

I've done a bunch of research on this and have found that BSD systems can't handle raw sockets the way Linux (or even Windows) does. From what I've read, it seems I need to use bpf (berkley packet filter), but I can't figure out how bpf works or how I would go about using it with raw sockets.

If someone could shed some light on this one, I'd be very excited :D

P.S. I'll even be happy with some source code showing how raw sockets are handled in a BSD environment. It doesn't have to be a guide or explanation. I just want to see how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using raw sockets isn't hard but it's not *entirely* portable. For instance, both in BSD and in Linux you can send whatever you want, but in BSD you can't receive anything that has a handler (like `TCP` and `UDP`).

Here is an example program that sends a `SYN`.

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sysexits.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int s, rc;
    struct protoent *p;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    struct tcphdr tcp;

    if (argc != 2)
        errx(EX_USAGE, "%s addr", argv[0]);

    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = 0;

    /* Parse command line address. */
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &sin.sin_addr) <= 0)
        err(EX_USAGE, "Parse address");

    /* Look up tcp although it's 6. */
    p = getprotobyname("tcp");
    if (p == NULL)
        err(EX_UNAVAILABLE, "getprotobyname");

    /* Make a new shiny (Firefly) socket. */
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, p->p_proto);
    if (s < 0)
        err(EX_OSERR, "socket");

    memset(&tcp, 0, sizeof(tcp));

    /* Fill in some random stuff. */
    tcp.th_sport = htons(4567);
    tcp.th_dport = htons(80);
    tcp.th_seq = 4; /* Chosen by fair dice roll. */
    tcp.th_ack = 0;
    tcp.th_off = 5;
    tcp.th_flags = TH_SYN;
    tcp.th_win = htonl(65535);

    rc = sendto(s, &tcp, sizeof(tcp), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sin,
        sizeof(sin));

    printf("Wrote %d bytes\n", rc);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, more BSD-specific solutions are available. For instance you could use [`divert(4)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=divert) to intercept packets as they traverse your system and alter them.