# How implement lwip on freebsd?

Tags: freebsd, lwip

I'm trying to to have a user land protocol stack on **freebsd** and i found **lwip** and download it.
but i'm new in freebsd and can not install it on **freebsd 10.1**.
please help me to install it and use it.any link or **tutorial**?

[I download it from this link](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/lwip/)

Comment: Why you need lwIP stack on FreeBSD? It has fully functional and more powerfull TCP stack.

Comment: I need to manage and set TCP and UDP packets manually like src and dest ip and ports and etc..

Comment: You can do this without lwip. For example see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048448/raw-sockets-on-bsd-operating-systems

Comment: I need send packets from my ip to my ip but through firewall and read received packets.